# In socket.py file, I see "import _socket" statement immediately followed by "from _socket import * ". What is the purpose?

Tags: python

```
# from cpython's socket.py
import _socket
from _socket import *
```

I get that if you don't want your current module to be exposed to everything in _socket file, you stick to the the former - otherwise the latter is the way to go. But what do you achieve exactly by combining the twos that way?

Comment: Maybe it's bringing the `_socket` namespace into the namespace of `socket.py` in both relative and absolute forms to serve multiple purposes/uses. I'm guessing the `socket` module is actually made up of multiple files/sub-modules, and the code itself will make use of the absolute namespace (i.e., using dot-notation to fully clarify a function or variable), but the module would like to make these functions available as part of the API to the user with relative notiation (e.g., `socket.socket` rather than say `socket.some_sub_module_name.socket`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, both imports are used for "overwriting" the base module with some extended behaviours.

[a link to the source at the current revision](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Lib/socket.py) - python/cpython (socket.py)

A few lines to demonstrate this:

The [getaddrinfo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Lib/socket.py#L726-L748) function desires to augment the `_socket.getaddrinfo` function, but it must call the base implementation, as such there's essentially two options:

1. `from _socket import getattrinfo as getaddrinfo_real` and use `getaddrinfo_real`
2. `import _socket` and reference directly `_socket.getaddrinfo`)

This module does the second.  The rest of the symbols (except a few others such as `class socket(_socket.socket):`) are just inherited from the `_socket` module.

Note that the `_socket` module [is implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Modules/socketmodule.c) -- the public interface to these C functions is in the `socket` module.  One may chose to implement parts of the functionality in python if it is easier, or if it is not performance critical, or if there aren't any low-level objects needed to be accessed.

The small bit of code I linked above:

```
def getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):

    # (Anthony Sottile): snipped for brevity

    # We override this function since we want to translate the numeric family
    # and socket type values to enum constants.
    addrlist = []
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),
                         _intenum_converter(socktype, SocketKind),
                         proto, canonname, sa))
    return addrlist
```

Comment: The module does both as it does `_realsocket = socket` before going on to subclass the socket class.

Comment: @Dunes Interesting, in the copy I linked it is assigned but unused -- perhaps only kept for legacy reasons (the `socket` class in the linked copy extends `_socket.socket`)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, consider a module named `module.py` which looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import submodule1
from submodule1 import *
import submodule2
from submodule2 import *
import submodule3
from submodule3 import *
```

This brings in the namespace of all three submodules both relatively and absolutely. Thus, we could make a reference to `function1` in `submodule1` in either of 2 ways:

```
submodule1.function1()
function1()
```

The former case is the Pythonic way, and is the way that calls to `function1` should be made in `module.py`. But, as a module, `module.py` may be made up of multiple files for readability's sake (grouping); but each of the submodules is really intended to be used as part of the `module.py` API.